# why this gradle error occur ? when building the project?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I've got a gradle FAILURE:
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.

As a result I couldn't build the app and I've got that FAILURE: message.[log cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vPZ0.jpg)

[graddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AEKH.png)

Comment: Post your `logcat` as well.

Comment: pls provide more details about error and build.gradle files

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vPZ0.jpg           here is the log cat

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AEKH.png          here is the graddle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the system broadcast intent ["android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION"] you are trying to use. This intent can not be used by non system app.

You can use MediaButton events. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons#mediabuttons-and-active-mediasessions